# Magento2.3.5 home page & admin panel is running very slow after doing cache: enable as well

Tags: admin, home-page, magento2.3.5, slow-response, loading

I have installed the Magento2.3.5 successfully with PHP 7.3 version. I am running magento on windows 10 laptop. When I open homepage & admin link it takes huge time to open. It keeps loading. Which is frustrating. Please suggest on this. I have done cache:enable from Magento too directory still it is slow. I have attached screenshots of homepage & admin pages.[image]

[image]

Comment: This link does not help. Please suggest another answer.

Comment: It's already done

Answer (score 0):

Run this command.

```
   php bin/magento cache:enable
```

For the first time it will load slow. Later on it will load very fast. Without caching magento is a miss.

Comment: How and where to run this command?

Comment: SSH to your magento root directory, and run that command.

Comment: I m running Magento locally on my pc windows 10 how to do that please provide steps. To complete soon. Thanks

Comment: you can enable cache from backend as well system>cache management

Comment: Done this but it is still working slow

Comment: Magento is a resource hungry software. may be your PC specifications are low according to magento2 standards. you should have latest pc or laptop with 8 to 16 GB of RAM

Comment: There is nothing to change in cache status comes when after running ur command